# Error Python "unexpected indent"

Tags: python, motor-de-juego

Soy estudiante y el profesor nos dio un código del juego "Adivinar el número" para ejecutar en Python pero no me deja ejecutarlo. Cuando lo intento, me aparece el **error "unexpected indent"**. ¿Cuál puede ser el motivo?

Éste es el **código**:

```
# Este es el juego de adivinar el número. 
import random 
 
intentosRealizados = 0 
 
print('¡Hola! ¿Cómo te llamas?') 
miNombre = input() 
 
número = random.randint(1, 20) 
print('Bueno, ' + miNombre + ', estoy pensando en un número entre 1 y 
') 
 
while intentosRealizados < 6: 
print('Intenta adivinar.') # Hay cuatro espacios delante de print. 
estimación = input() 
estimación = int(estimación) 
 
intentosRealizados = intentosRealizados + 1 
 
if estimación < número: 
print('Tu estimación es muy baja.') # Hay ocho espacios delante de print. 
 
if estimación > número: 
print('Tu estimación es muy alta.') 
 
if estimación == número: 
break 
 
if estimación == número: 
intentosRealizados = str(intentosRealizados) 
print('¡Buen trabajo, ' + miNombre + '! ¡Has adivinado mi número en ' + 
intentosRealizados + ' intentos!') 
 
if estimación != número: 
número = str(número) 
print('Pues no. El número que estaba pensando era ' + número)
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a stackoverflow en español. Al añadir el código, solamente copia el código sin enumerar las líneas. De esta forma das facilidad a la comunidad de copiar el código para ayudar a resolver cualquier problema que puedas tener. Te invito a revisar como preguntar: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask] saludos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tienes un error de indentación del código.

Los bloques de instrucciones en python pueden ir dentro de otro bloque de instrucciones. Por ejemplo los condicionales, como if, al colocar los dos puntos ":", el código que quieres que se ejecute si se cumple la condición tiene que ir tabulado.

1. Un punto importante: estás utilizando nombre de variables con tildes, no es lo correcto. Puedes mirar un apartado de "variable syntax" para revisar como escribirlas de forma correcta. Por ejemplo:

   - No pueden comenzar con número.
   - Debe comenzar con letra o con guión bajo.
   - Sólo puede tener caracteres alfanuméricos (letras de la A-Z o a-z, números 0-9, guión bajo).
2. El código arroja el siguiente error:

   `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'`
   esto es porque estás reasignando cuando estimación es distinto a número de esta forma: `número = str(número)`. Lo estás convirtiendo a string, cuando estás comparando enteros.

Además de la indentación he cambiado lo siguiente en el código:

De:

```
if estimación != número: 
        número = str(número) 
        print('Pues no. El número que estaba pensando era ' + número)
```

A:

```
if estimación != número:
        print('Pues no. El número que estaba pensando era ' + str(número))
```

De esta forma no reasignas la variable de int a string y solamente la conviertes cuando imprimes.

El código quedaría así (sin corregir lo de las tildes):

```
# Este es el juego de adivinar el número. 
import random

intentosRealizados = 0

print('¡Hola! ¿Cómo te llamas?')
miNombre = input()

número = random.randint(1, 20)
print('Bueno, ' + miNombre + ', estoy pensando en un número entre 1 y 20.')

while intentosRealizados < 6:
    print('Intenta adivinar.') # Hay cuatro espacios delante de print. 
    estimación = input()
    estimación = int(estimación)

    intentosRealizados = intentosRealizados + 1

    if estimación < número:
        print('Tu estimación es muy baja.') # Hay ocho espacios delante de print. 

    if estimación > número:
        print('Tu estimación es muy alta.')

    if estimación == número:
        break

    if estimación == número:
        intentosRealizados = str(intentosRealizados)
        print('¡Buen trabajo, ' + miNombre + '! ¡Has adivinado mi número en ' + intentosRealizados + ' intentos!')

    if estimación != número:
        print('Pues no. El número que estaba pensando era ' + str(número))
```