# No logro entender porque me sale error en python. ERROR : IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python, compilar, booleano, basic

Estoy iniciando en esto de la programación, y me dieron un ejercicio básico. Tengo que crear un programa donde solo puede ingresar personas de 18 hasta los 65 años inclusive. El objetivo del programa es que me devuelva una respuesta boolean.

Por ahora lo que voy haciendo es esto:

```
print("Ingrese edad")
edad = int (input("Edad"))
if edad <= 18 or edad >= 65:
print ("No puedes entrar")
```

Pero me dice que tengo un error en la línea 4. ¿Si resuelvo ese error, el programa funcionará correctamente? Y si no es así, ¿Qué mas le faltaría?
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: podrías agregar el mensaje de error de python en la pregunta?

Comment: si 18 y 65 son inclusive (validas, por la definicón del problema) entonces tienes que usar `<` y `>`, sin los `=`s.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo hice pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error: IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: bueno... en ese código la línea 4 sale indentada correctamente... así que me suena a que el error no es específicamente de la sección que tienes copiada en la pregunta.... si te es posible, por todo el código del script y el error tal cual _como parte de la pregunta_.

Comment: Parece problema de inconsistencia de indentación respecto a otras partes del código ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error Python unexpected indent](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/386924/80870)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error Python "unexpected indent"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/386922/error-python-unexpected-indent)

Comment: Si, muchas gracias y perdon la demora!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python es muy estricto con el formato de tu código. Si los bloques no están indentados correctamente, vas a experimentar [`IndentationError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html?highlight=indentation#IndentationError). Para identificarlos, simplemente revisa la línea reportada y realiza las correcciones necesarias:

```
edad = int(input('Ingrese edad: '))

if edad <= 18 or edad >= 65:
    print("No puedes entrar.")
else:
    print("Puedes entrar.")
```

Si necesitas que el programa te devuelva un booleano, entonces conviene crear una función que retorne el resultado de evaluar la edad expresado en `True` or `False`. Quiza, algo así:

```
def confirmar_acceso(edad):
    if edad <= 18 or edad >= 65:
        return False
    else:
        return True


print(confirmar_acceso(int(input('Ingrese edad: '))))
```

La [guía de estilos oficial de Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) recomienda utilizar 4 espacios por nivel de indentación.

Comment: Muy buena la sugerencia de hacer la función para que devuelva un boolean... lo único que le cambiaría es que haga el return directamente sobre la verificación del condicional: `return edad >= 18 and edad <= 65`

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Como tenías la pregunta originalmente era correcto:

```
print("Ingrese edad")
edad = int (input("Edad"))
if edad <= 18 or edad >= 65:
  print ("No puedes entrar")
```

En el código que tienes actualmente en la pregunta está el error de que no indentaste la línea 4. La linea 4 tiene que estar corrida a la derecha porque está *dentro* del if. Tienes que ponerle 2, 4 espacios o un tab al inicio de la línea.

Es una de las cosas que más me gusta de python: te *obliga* a ser ordenado con la indentación. Pocas cosas me desagradan más en un programa que tener las indentaciones por todos lados (... bueno, hay algo que le gana fácilmemte: ver código comentado que debió ser borrado.... **ugh**... como si no existieran los VCSs para ayudarnos a recuperar código viejo)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!